# Imageview won't resize in container unless I tap twice

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a simple UIView, and inside an imageview. The idea is to have the UIView resize programmatically, and the image view inside automatically stretch so it's always same size.
For the sake of simplicity I will skip all the parts where I calculate the size needed, but here is the code that is supposed to resize UIView (containerView2) AND ImageView (imageHolder2):

```
    imageHolder2.clipsToBounds = true
    containerView2.clipsToBounds = true

    //Resize  UIView
    var ff : CGRect = containerView2.frame
    ff.size.width = 175 * aspectRatio
    ff.size.height = 175
    containerView2.frame = ff

    //Resize ImageView to same size, which is inside UIView
    var tt : CGRect = imageHolder2.frame
    tt.size.width = 175 * aspectRatio
    tt.size.height = 175
    imageHolder2.frame = tt

    containerView2.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    imageHolder2.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
```

All this is in a IBAction button. What is strange, is that when I tap the button once, it will resize the UIView but NOT the ImageView. But when I tap a second time, then it will correctly resize the imageView. Why is that? And how to fix this?
Note that I use autolayout and constraint on this project, in this view, but NOT on elements involved in this code.

Please answer in Swift.

Comment: So, are these 2 views created in code?

Comment: No I added them to storyboard, then ctrl+drag to create the IBoutlets in view controller.

Comment: If they're in the same storyboard as your other views for which you use auto layout, then these views use auto layout also -- if you don't add constraints, the system adds them for you. Auto layout is on or off for the whole storyboard.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same storyboard.
So what should I do, add those 2 views programmatically ? Could this solve the issue even if auto layout is used on the storyboard ? I never tried before to add views purely programmatically.

Comment: You either need to add the views programmatically, or use constraints to resize your views. You shouldn't set any frames when you're using auto layout.

Comment: but can I set frames on programmatically added views, even in the context of an auto layout project ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that (but personally, I would stick with constraints).

Comment: I did what you suggested and acted on auto layout constraint. It took 30 minutes and 3 lines of codes to achieve what I was trying to achieve since 8 hours. You can create an answer and i'll select it as solution. Thanks.